# Fetch Facebook stories vith API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to fetch facebook stories using api? Under stories i mean short videos, shown on top part of mobile app. I specified it because in facebook documentation all posts sometimes called stories, which is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I did my research, there are no APIs for now in Facebook Development Documentations

Comment: Yes, i asked about this at official FB developers group, and they say there is no API for this, because stories should not be stored anywhere, only 24h hours shown, and then deleted.

Comment: And do you believe that? :p

Comment: Totally, meaning of stories is that it should not be stored. Same situation in instagram and vkontakte social network, there is no api to fetch stories.

Comment: I mean, do you believe they don't store longer than 24 hours? That what Snapchat used to say but not after the server hack in 2015.