# Create Facebook story via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any Graph API to create or fetch stories (those short posts that live only 24 hours) from Facebook? There was a similar question back in 2017 ([Fetch Facebook stories vith API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208047/fetch-facebook-stories-vith-api)). Has anything changed since then?

Comment: Hi, is there any update on this matter?